# apply a filter to x[n] in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, signal-processing

What's the most clever way to apply a FIR filter in Python to `x[n]` (for all `n <= N`)

```
y[n] = a[0]*x[n] + a[1]*x[n-1] + a[2]*x[n-2] + ... + a[K]*x[n-K]
```

I know how to do this with a double `for` loop, but I imagine there are more "beautiful" ways to write it in Python?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
y[n] = sum(a[k]*x[n-K] for k in xrange(K + 1))
```

This uses the built-in [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) functions and a generator expression to compute the final result.

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a solution with lists / arrays like 
`y[n] = sum(a * reverse(x[n-K:n]) )` ?

Comment: Other thing : is there a way to define `x[k] = 0` when `k` is negative ? If it's impossible, how to deal with `x[n-K]` when `n < K` ?

Comment: Not sure about the arrays but I suppose you could do `(0 if k < 0 else x[n-K])` instead of `x[n-K]`.

Answer (score 1):

This avoids the use of an index:

```
y[n] = sum(aa * xx for aa, xx in zip(a, x[n::-1]))
```

A cool thing about `zip` is that the length of its output will be the length of the shorter of the two inputs.

To do this for all `n`, it's probably easiest to use an index for the outer loop:

```
y = [sum(aa * xx for aa, xx in zip(a, x[n::-1])) for n in xrange(0, len(x))]
```

You could replace `xrange(0, len(x))` with something like `xrange(len(a), len(x))` if you want to include only the "valid" terms (terms that use a sum across all coefficients in `a`).

If this is something you're going to be doing a lot, or doing with large inputs, I would suggest checking out Numpy, specifically its `convolve` function. That implementation will be much faster than the one I've described here.

Comment: Beautiful indeed ! The use of `zip` is great, then I don't need to distinguish `if n<K then do something else than x[n-K]` ...

Comment: what's the best method to create the list y ?
`y = []` ; `for n in range(N):` ; `y.append(sum(aa * xx ....))` 
Or is there a best method to fill the list `y`?

Comment: @JosBas: You could use an explicit for loop, like you suggested, but I prefer list comprehensions. See my edited answer.

Comment: thanks for your comments.
Given the **taps** array a[n] of a FIR filter, what's the traditional way to compute the output `y[n]` of the filter ? `convolve`?

Comment: Yep, `convolve` is what you want. Scipy also has a function `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` that uses the FFT and multiplication instead of explicit convolution; whether this is faster or not will depend on the specific characteristics of your inputs. Generally, I think if your filter is short (up to 1000 elements or so), `convolve` will probably be faster, but for longer filters you might want to look at `fftconvolve`. I'm just guessing on those numbers, though, really you have to test on your hardware for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

For signal processing, you should really make use of NumPy. In particular, filtering a signal will just be [convolution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html), making this a one-liner.